# Baking grid texture on normal map

Tags: materials, node-editor, baking

What's the best way to bake this kind of grid on a texture with preserving the current level of details? I tried simple normal baking but there is this quality loss.

[image: Normal map]

Comment: You probably need a high resolution image, or maybe use a small map, as it is repeatable it is not a problem if you unwrap orthogonal UVs?

Comment: Alright, thank you! I'll try that.